# Incorrect mapping for Jackson model with nested JSON and name as variable

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, robospice

I'm getting the following error when trying to get a response using RoboSpice with Jackson mapping do to an incorrect mapping for the error JSON returned

```
POST request for "https://****/api/register?email=jam@yum.com&first_name=Vege&last_name=Mite&password=qwerty12345&invite_token=oXlTvAvbVR5fiQP6DKCEVQ" 
resulted in 422 (Unprocessable Entity); invoking error handler
E//RequestRunner.java:134﹕ 19:01:34.881 Thread-15097 An exception occurred during request network execution :422 Unprocessable Entity
```

using Curl I get the following correct response:

```
{"object":"Error","errors":{"email":["has already been taken"]}}
```

My Model Object for the repose that is failing is as follows, the issue is the "errors" item not mapping correctly but I am not sure what it should be since the variable name "email" can change (i.e. "agent", "vendor" , etc..)

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BaseModel {
private String id;
private String email;
private String first_name;
private String last_name;
private String street1;
private String street2;
private String city;
private String state;
private String zipcode;
private String country;
private String phone;
private String create_at;
private String object;
private Map<String, ArrayList<String>> errors;

//Getters and Setters Removed
```

Comment: If your server returns 422 there might be a problem with the request itself and not with the response. Double check the request payload and the content type.

Comment: The 422 only returns if the email already exists or another type of error result needs to be returned. If not I get the correct results and app processes the the BaseModel correctly.

An example is I can delete this email from the server and the query above will run and return , translated to BaseModel without any issues

Comment: Which extension (Sprint, Google Http Client, ect) are you using?